# How to apply a for-loop to each python list item?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I'm new to stackoverflow and I'm working on a python challenge where: Given a string, I must return the number of occurrences of each word in the string.

I have a code written and what I'd like is to have my for-loop continually run each word in the string, but it only runs for a "placeholder variable" I included to represent words in the string.

Here's the code:

```
d={}

vari='When I find myself in times of trouble Mother Mary comes to me Speaking words of wisdom let it be And in my hour of darkness she is standing right in front of me Speaking words of wisdom let it be Let it be let it be let it be let it be Whisper words of wisdom let it be And when the broken hearted people living in the world agree There will be an answer let it be For though they may be parted there is still a chance that they will see There will be an answer let it be Let it be let it be let it be let it be There will be an answer let it be Let it be let it be let it be let it be Whisper words of wisdom let it be Let it be let it be let it be let it be Whisper words of wisdom let it be And when the night is cloudy there is still a light that shines on me Shine until tomorrow let it be I wake up to the sound of music Mother Mary comes to me Speaking words of wisdom let it be Let it be let it be let it be yeah let it be There will be an answer let it be Let it be let it be let it be yeah let it be Whisper words of wisdom let it be'.split()

for c in vari:
    d['c']=vari.count('c');

for key,value in d.items():
    print key,
    print value
```

Sorry for the long string. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Cheat a little and use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)!

Comment: Also you'd want to use `c` (your iterator variable) instead of `'c'` which is a string literal "c".

Comment: @AkshatMahajan Cheat!? Is using a library for its exact intended purpose considered cheating these days? :-D

Comment: @foslock Well, OP did say it was for a challenge.

Answer (score 2):

> Given a string, I must return the number of occurrences of each word in the string.

This can be accomplished by **splitting** the string in a **list** of words, iterating over each word, keeping track of how many times it has previously been seen. **The below examples assume that case of the word does matter.** One can use the `lower()` method on the strings to turn it into a case-insensitive count.

### Vanilla Approach

```
sentence = 'My very very long string'

words = sentence.split()
counts = {}
for word in words:
    if word not in counts:
        counts[word] = 1
    else:
        counts[word] += 1

print(counts)
```

This prints out the dictionary you want:

```
{'very': 2, 'My': 1, 'string': 1, 'long': 1}
```

### Counter Class (from collections package)

If you don't mind importing a standard library, you can use the `collections.Counter` class instead of a native `dict`. It's values default to 0 for unassigned keys, making it useful for this exact use case.

```
import collections
counter = collections.Counter(words)
print(counter)
```

This is a dictionary-like object that contains the same information as above:

```
Counter({'very': 2, 'My': 1, 'string': 1, 'long': 1})
```

Comment: You may also want to perform `lower` on the string prior to splitting and passing to the `Counter`. Reason for this is that it will not count words with different capitalization as separate words. The first word in the string is `When`, if there is a `when` anywhere it will be counted as 2 words.

Comment: @PaulRooney That is correct, although it depends entirely up to the situation whether the client wants words counted case-insensitive or not. Based on the question it seems like they want a case-sensitive count.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the literal String `'c'` as the key for each word, pass the variable `c` that is initialized at each step within your `for` loop as the key.

```
for c in vari:
    d[c]=vari.count(c)
```

Alternatively you can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

words = vari.split()
wordCount = Counter(words)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be as compact as this:

```
result = {word:vari.split().count(word) for word in vari.split()}
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes surrounding 'c':

```
d={}

vari='When I find myself in times of trouble Mother Mary comes to me Speaking words of wisdom let it be And in my hour of darkness she is standing right in front of me Speaking words of wisdom let it be Let it be let it be let it be let it be Whisper words of wisdom let it be And when the broken hearted people living in the world agree There will be an answer let it be For though they may be parted there is still a chance that they will see There will be an answer let it be Let it be let it be let it be let it be There will be an answer let it be Let it be let it be let it be let it be Whisper words of wisdom let it be Let it be let it be let it be let it be Whisper words of wisdom let it be And when the night is cloudy there is still a light that shines on me Shine until tomorrow let it be I wake up to the sound of music Mother Mary comes to me Speaking words of wisdom let it be Let it be let it be let it be yeah let it be There will be an answer let it be Let it be let it be let it be yeah let it be Whisper words of wisdom let it be'.split()

for c in vari:
    d[c]=vari.count(c);

for key,value in d.items():
    print key,
    print value
```

Comment: Wrong actually. Your original code worked perfectly fine. Adding a space in `split()` is only superfluous as `split()` splits on white-space anyway.

Comment: Yeah, just compiled it. Changing it back!

Comment: I guess I missed the 'split' part at the end of the long string.

Comment: seems more legible to do `vari.split()` rather than `vari = 'some very long string'.split().  The results are same of course...